# How to include count in return list of AppDbContext

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing a query to get the details of a Batch and I want to include the count of records that are part of that Batch, with some filters in the middle.

Currently my function looks like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Batch>> GetAllBatchSummary(BatchFilter filter)
        {


            return await _dbContext.Batch
                .Where(b => b.BatchDetails.Count(bd => bd.RecordStatus == filter.RecordStatus) > 0)
                .Include(b => b.ProcessType)
                .OrderBy(b => b.ProcessTypeId)
                .Select(b => new
                {
                    Batch = b,
                    BatchDetailsCount = b.BatchDetails.Count(bd => bd.RecordStatus == filter.RecordStatus)
                })
                .Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize)
                .Take(filter.PageSize)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

But its getting an error because the return type is not the one expected:

CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: PaymentGateway.Domain.Entities.ProcessControl.Batch Batch, int BatchDetailsCount>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PaymentGateway.Domain.Entities.ProcessControl.Batch>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I've already tried to use SelectMany() and .AsEnumerable() but didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your method's return type is `Task<IEnumerable<Batch>>`, but you are returning some anonymous type's value obtained in the lambda expression. Can you please share the model `Batch` class to look deeper

Answer (score 3):

Your method is returning anon type but expecting `Task<IEnumerable<Batch>>`

Create a model something like `BatchDto` and map the properties there.

```
public class BatchDto
{
    public int BatchDetailsCount { get; set; }
    public Batch Batch { get; set; }
}

public async Task<List<BatchDto> GetAllBatchSummary(BatchFilter filter)
{
    return await _dbContext.Batch
        .Where(b => b.BatchDetails.Count(bd => bd.RecordStatus == filter.RecordStatus) > 0)
        .Include(b => b.ProcessType)
        .OrderBy(b => b.ProcessTypeId)
        .Select(b => new BatchDto
        {
            Batch = b,
            BatchDetailsCount = b.BatchDetails.Count(bd => bd.RecordStatus == filter.RecordStatus)
        })
        .Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize)
        .Take(filter.PageSize)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Just applied your solution, but it's giving me an error
Error mapping types.
 Mapping types:
 List`1 -> IEnumerable`1
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PaymentGateway.Domain.Entities.ProcessControl.BatchResponse, PaymentGateway.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[PaymentGateway.Application.DTOs.ProcessControl.BatchDto, PaymentGateway.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Any suggestion?

Comment: @StackJP My bad, just updated the return type to `List<BatchDto>`